# Null Reference exception when accessing a singleton with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm getting null reference exception when trying to access a singleton class from my ASP.NET MVC Controller Action. I use Autofac as the IoC Container.

*Here is the code:*

Register dependencies method:

```
public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        const string nameOrConnectionString = "name=DefaultConnection";
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(WebApiConfig).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.Register<IEntitiesContext>(b =>
        {
            var logger = b.Resolve<ILogger>();
            var context = new InterfaceContext(nameOrConnectionString, logger);
            return context;
        }).InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(b => NLogLogger.Instance).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(b => UserControlHelper.Instance).SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterModule(new IdentityModule());

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
             new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

UserControlHelper class:

```
public class UserControlHelper
{
    private static volatile UserControlHelper _instance;
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

    private static IService<Administrator> _service;
    private static IService<Customer> _customerService;


    private UserControlHelper() { }

    private UserControlHelper(IService<Administrator> service, IService<Customer> customerService)
    {
        _service = service;
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    public static UserControlHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new UserControlHelper(_service, _customerService);
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public static string GetUserData(int userId, string type)
    {
        var getImage = _service.GetByIdAsync(userId);

        switch (type)
        {
            case "Image":
                {
                    return getImage.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Image;
                }
            case "Name":
                {
                    return getImage.GetAwaiter().GetResult().FullName;
                }
            case "Email":
                {
                    return getImage.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Email;
                }

            case "AllUsers":
                {
                    return _customerService.GetCountAsync(userId).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
                }

            default:
                return "No Data";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

> ViewBag.FullName = UserControlHelper.GetUserData(UserId, "Name");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your _service variable is going to be null all the time. Hence you maybe getting the null referece.

```
private static IService<Administrator> _service;
```

This variable is never instantiated (manually or via Autofac)

And when you call your method, this is the code that might be causing the null reference.

```
    var getImage = _service.GetByIdAsync(userId);
```

because `_service` is null

For all the Autofac wireup being done, there is no place we are indicating to Autofac that this class needs to be instantiated automatically. The class doesn't seem to be a controller (MVC or API) or any dependencies to the controller.

Also, the `_service` variable being static doesn't help with Autofac.

To solve the problem, you might want to rethink this class in terms of a controller or better, a dependency (constructor parameter) to a controller, with the _service and such variables as instance variables rather than static variables, where Autofac cannot help you much.

This way, when the controller is instantiated by Autofac, it'll automatically create an instance of '`UserControlHelper`' for you.

Answering to your comment (You need a singleton of UserControlHelper):

1. you can leverage Autofac for this.
2. we'll make this class a constructor parameter of your controller.
3. And let Autofac know to instantiate this as a singleton.

   ```
   public class MyController: Controller
   {
    public MyController(UserControlHelper helper)
    {
     ViewBag.FullName = helper.GetUserData(UserId, "Name");
    }
   }
   ```

And when you register this class with Autofac, you can do:

```
build.RegisterType<UserControlHelper>().SingleInstance();
```

This would mean that you have to remove the Instance variable and any singleton-like logic in your class. And also convert the static methods to instance methods. And convert the constructor to a public one.

It is best to let Autofac/frameworks do the grunt work of Singletons/other such functionality. (Lazy variables are another such tool)

And we can focus on keeping your class relevant to the business logic.

And if you really want to do the singleton implementation yourself, you can still register it with autofac as:

```
builder.RegisterInstance<UserControlHelper>(singletonInstanceYouConstructed);
```

But in general, I have found it to be simpler to let Autofac manage the whole lifetime management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i want to make UserControl Helper class to be instantiated only once and i thought i should implement singleton. Can you please tell me with code how i can achieve this? or using autofac? does it make sense to register this class with autofac?

Comment: @Anony i have edited my answer to answer your question in the comment

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It worked!. But it only works if i set InstancePerLifetimeScope() instead of single instance. Would it make any concern as long as im implementing singleton?